# Apple Watch WCSession return watchAppInstalled false

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wcsession

I have an Apple Watch app and works perfect on simulators (watch simulator and iPhone simulator). When I run the app on real devices, the `WCSession` `watchAppInstalled` property is false, but I have the application on a watch, so I can't start it from watch device.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the watch app. In Watch on the iPhone you select your application and switch the "Show app on Apple Watch" off then on again.

The solution was found [here](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/watchos2-watchkit-connectivity/).

Comment: Was the problem that you had not set a delegate and activated the session?

Answer (score 2):

Before calling isWatchAppInstalled you must first

1. Assign a `WCSessionDelegate` to `WCSession.default.delegate`
2. Call `WCSession.default.activate()`

Otherwise (on WatchOS 5 at least), `isWatchAppInstalled` will always return `false`.